# Yii Framework, JSON API, Restricted by URL

Tags: api, authentication, yii

I am trying to build an API service for my Yii based website,

I have create an API controller with all the functions that returns objects in JSON format.

I also created a system to generate API keys for a specific URL... but I cant seem to understand how to detect the url from where the call is being made to my api so I can compare and validate.

I have tryed with HTTP_REFERER ...not working...

Any idea how is this possible ?

Thanks

Comment: without knowing more specifics about how you are connecting to your service, etc., it's hard to tell what the problem is -- have you tried viewing the output of all server variables, like `print_r($_SERVER)`?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer
```

or

```
Yii::app()->request->host
```

or

```
Yii::app()->request->hostAddress
```

for more details see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest